# Node.js module for WebRTC data channels usage?

Tags: node.js, sockets, webrtc

I am writing a multiplayer real time game for the browser with the server as a master instance and the clients as input devices and slaves to show the graphics.

I have to send out changes in the game world very often and very fast and it doesn't matter if some of the data sometimes gets lost on the way because a couple of milliseconds later there will be the next update anyway.

Right now I am using Socket.io to talk between the server and the clients but this uses TCP which makes the update come in unnecessary late sometimes.

I know that there is WebRTC with data channels where I would be able to send my updates through wit UDP which would be very awesome and exactly what I want. And it even seems to be implemented in Firefox and Chrome already https://stackoverflow.com/a/12864512/63779

What I now need is some Node library which would allow me to use data channels to send my data (for now just JSON strings) with help of UDP to the clients which are browsers. On the browser I would be able to use webkitRTCPeerConnection() but I have no idea how to start something like that on the Node server. Any suggestions? If there is no Node module for that, would it be possible to write something in some other language and just send the data via Unix domain sockets or something?

Comment: Why do you think your updates over TCP make them unnecessarily late?  If that's happening you probably have packet loss issues already, which will be disastrous over UDP.

Comment: Because TCP ensures that every data packet is delivered which is not necessary and only slows everything down. If for example package #200 is lost but package #201 is already there it will not be delivered but instead the server will resend package #200 again, package #201 remains in the pipeline untill #200 was delivered even if it has newer data which will overwrite the information in #200 anyway.

Comment: Yes, TCP ensures packets reach their destination and reach it in the correct order.  Also, be very careful with the assumption that your data is making it to its endpoint without fragmentation.

Comment: Yeah, once I find a way to send UDP to the browser I will need to learn all about that stuff. What I would like to send this way are only position updates a couple of times a second.

Comment: I was looking for a WebRTC peer for Node.js awhile back.  The only thing I could find required compilation of libjingle from Chromium, and I never really did get it working.